# Выпадение Е в слове "жевать"

Tags: словообразование

По какому правилу/принципу из слова "жевать" выпадает буква Е в словах "жвачка", "жвала"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это элизия. Гласная "е" выпала из слова для благозвучия.

> **Элизия** (от лат. ēlīsiō «выдавливание»,
> «выталкивание») в лингвистике —
> отпадение звука (гласного, согласного
> или слога) в слове или фразе с целью
> облегчения произношения для
> говорящего. Иногда звуки могут быть
> опущены с целью улучшения благозвучия.    
> Википедия.

Comment: А что, "жевачка" говорить трудно? Почему же неграмотные люди часто именно так говорят? Ведь кажется, если человек не следит за правилами, он будет говорить так, как ему удобно. Вообще чередование согласных и гласных гораздо удобнее, чем скопление согласных. Например, татары при произношении русских слов часто вставляют лишние согласные: икыс вместо икс и т.п.

Comment: Кстати, и японцы точно также. У них же слоговое письмо, так что практически все слова в языке представляют собой чередование "гласный-согласный". Поэтому очень забавно слушать, как они говорят по-английски, добавляя гласные между согласными и на конце слов)))